# create dynamic radio buttons and to check only one radio button and uncheck the rest

Tags: android

i want to create a form having type_of_service, name, ph.no,...etc. In type of service, the types are specified using radio buttons. which are comming dynamicaly from asp webservice.. it may be 1, 2 or 10..
i have to select only one choice from the type of service... and then after selecting the choice and fillng up the form and on clicking the submit button i have to pass the value of the radio button selected to the payment gateway(paypal)...

i hav probs with creating the radio button dynamically and selecting one of it... and deselecting the rest of the radio buttons...
and how to check which radio button is selected so i an pass the corresponding  value..

plz help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
LinearLayout layout_name = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_name);
final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
        rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
            rg.addView(rb[i]); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout
            rb[i].setId(i);//Setting id for the RadioButton
            rb[i].setText("Test");
        }
        rg.check(3);//Checking pirticular RadioButton with id
        // 3 is that RadioButton Id name
        layout_name.addView(rg);//you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout
```

**EDIT:**

```
 int selected = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 String type =rb[selected].getText().toString(); 
 Log.d("type", type);
```